# how to access values of an object with dynamic keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this code

```
    bodyLength.map((el, i) => {
      console.log(`${values.bodyTitleEn2 + i.toString()}`);

      body.push({
        title: [
          {
            key: 'en',
            value: values.bodyTitleEn + i,
          },
          {
            key: 'ku',
            value: values.bodyTitleKu + i,
          },
          {
            key: 'ar',
            value: values.bodyTitleAr + i,
          },
        ] ...
```

`values.bodyTitleEn` , `Ku` , and `Ar` have a number at the end of them, which means `values.bodyTitleEn0`, `values.bodyTitleEn1`, `values.bodyTitleEn2`, and I have this array `bodyLength` which is equal to the length of how many of `bodyTitle[En]` are there, so I'm trying to achieve `values.bodyTitleEn + i` to add the number at the end dynamically, but it says `undefined values.bodyTitleEn`, because `bodyTitleEn` never exists in the object without the number at the end of it, how can I achieve this thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append the number like this:

```
values[`bodyTitleEn${i}`]
```

the above syntax will try to get the value of the key `bodyTitleEn0`, `bodyTitleEn1`...

when you use `values.bodyTitleEn + i`, you're trying to add the number to the value returned by `values.bodyTitleEn` but like you noticed the values object doesn't have the key `bodyTitleEn` and even if it has the key, that's not what you want to do.

Comment: yep I see that, thanks for the answer u saved me so much time :) cheers

Comment: @LhonRafaatMohammed See [Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names).